# Como representar uma interface em xml em uma diagrama de classes? (projeto Android)

Tags: android, uml

Tenho um projeto Android, que uso vários arquivos "xml" de layout como interface. Como devo representá-los no diagrama de classes. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você deve ignorar os XMLs de layout e representar as activities, Fragments  e Views. o diagrama de classe representa somente as classes. OS XMLs são carregados pelo Android Framework e nossas activities pegam a instancia pela referencia gerada na classe R.

Comment: Só represente classes. :D